# Using external URLs in Django's TEMPLATE_DIRS

Tags: python, django, django-settings

Django's TEMPLATE_DIRS in Settings.py calls for unix style slashes.

Because of this, when I call

```
get_template('some/template.html')
```

in a view, the result always starts at the root, and results in a call to

```
/home/username/projectname/public/some/template.html
```

The problem is that I'd like to use templates hosted on an entirely different site. This works fine for other Settings.py fields (MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL), where it will take an absolute http path with no objection.

Given an http path,

```
 TEMPLATE_DIRS ('http://example.com/',)
```

in Settings.py will force

```
get_template('some/template.html')
```

in a view to try and find

```
/home/username/projectname/public/http://example.com/some/template.html
```

I've tried to circumvent this like so

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS ('../../../../http://example.com/',)
```

But it still forces a leading slash, so I get "/http://example.com", which is useless.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to trick this into pulling the template files from
   another server?

   Is that even feasible, given that the template files need to be
   processed for the view?

   Is it possible to create an alternate to 'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader' that doesn't call for unix style slashes?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use the template directory is you dont want to. If you have a server that is serving template files, you can simply fetch them remotely using `urllib2` and create and render the template with a context manually:

```
import urllib2
from django.template import Context, Template

tpl_html = urllib2.urlopen("http://mysite.com")
tpl = Template(tpl_html)
return tpl.render(Context({
    'some_variable' : 'some_val',
})
```

If you are going to do this, you have to incorporate some caching, as for every request to using this template, you need to make an external request. Alternatively you could write this into a custom loader but it will suffer the same limitations.

Comment: This worked for me with the following minor change in the return statement: `return HttpResponse(tpl.render(Context({...})))`

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this.

It has nothing to do with path names. It's just that the filesystem template loader needs to load things from the filesystem, hence the name.

This is completely different from the case of MEDIA_URL: that simply adds a path into your HTML, which your browser then loads. Django doesn't care where that file lives: although in fact the opposite applies, in that if you pass it a filepath that isn't a URL (ie served by a webserver somewhere), it simply won't work.

Now, you *could* write a template loader that gets its templates from another server. Template loaders are pluggable - you just need to put the name of your new loader in the TEMPLATE_LOADERS setting. The loader itself would need to use something like `urllib.urlopen` to get the template from the external server.

But think very carefully before you do this. This means that *every single template request* now requires a call to an external server before you can serve the page. In the typical case of a template that extends other templates and includes calls to included template tags, that might be five or ten calls. And, unlike media files, it can't be done in parallel: the page simply won't be served until the whole process is finished. This is likely to make your webserver very very slow.

I don't know why you think you need to do this. Templates are part of your application code, so they would normally live on the same server as your Python code. If you really have some reason to keep them externally, one solution might be to mount the external filesystem onto your webserver via something like [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). It's still likely to be very slow though. Think again.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is atypical, and would disappear with deployment. The server I'd deploy to is slow to reflect changes to the filesystem, even when fcgi is killed and restarted. As a result, I've been developing on the django-friendly anydata.com. It's much faster and smoother, but there's a 10MB storage limit, so to avoid hitting that limit I've been hosting as much as I can in other locations.

Still, what you said makes sense, and in this instance it's definitely preferable to have the relatively small template files local, rather than take the performance hit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. No - it's not possible to trick it into pulling files from another server via http
2. Yes - you certainly could subclass django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader (and by altering the load_template_source method appropriately) so that you could load templates via http

Once you had done 3 then the answer to 2 would be yes - it would be feasible - ultimately Django's template language doesn't care where it gets the file from, as long it's in the right format.

However, it seems like a very inefficient way of loading templates and more likely there is a much better way of achieving the same result.