# Is there a way to define a remote template path for Django CMS

Tags: python, django, django-cms

For the final stages of a Django CMS site we were able to serve the static files from remote:

Simply by changing the **setting.py**'s STATIC URL variable from:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

to:

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://hosting-****.firebaseapp.com'
```

Is there a way to change the path of the templates html files as well? We want to be able to quickly change both css and templates as QA tests the site.

I have stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201192/using-external-urls-in-djangos-template-dirs) that suggests to build a template loader:

```
def load_template_source(template_name, template_dirs=None):
try:
    tpl_html = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com")
    tpl = Template(tpl_html)
    return HttpResponse(tpl.render(Context({
        'some_variable': 'some_val',
    })))
except IOError:
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name)
```

But being new to Django, I am not sure how to build and register a new template loader and couldn't find relevant documentation. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: more investigation led me to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201192/using-external-urls-in-djangos-template-dirs

Comment: Since static files and templates work very differently, there is no (simple) solution. Considering security, there is none. Also your question indicates that it might be a good idea to revise your QA and deployment process.

Comment: @KlausD. As a freelancer, I have no access to my client's django CMS server so I cannot change templates once deployed (It can only be access from the office's IP and requires authorization). We want to deploy an initial version so several people can play with the site. However I need a way to quickly patch html and css issues - hence the need to build a template loader that serves remote HTML. performance is not an issue at this point.