# How do I emit the HTML of an external website in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, urllib, django-cms

I want to get the contents of one of my pages on an external site, the HTML and all contents.  If were in .NET I could use WebClient and retrieve the page, save it to a variable, and emit it in Razor.  PHP can use cURL.

How can I do that in a Django template?  Do I need to create a Plugin that uses urllib?

If it matters, I am using DjangoCMS.  I searched and tried the Django http module.

I have looked at the helper Django module for http and didn't see anything.  I wasn't sure where to put `urllib` or `requests`, as in I do not know if what I am trying to do requires me to build a plugin or a custom template tag.

I was hoping to know how to do it with either Python and Django's template language or just the template language, so I really do not want to do this in JavaScript, [iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925529/how-to-use-iframes-in-django-cms), object, etc.

Comment: for starters you can write a function in your views.py with the requests module, just few lines of code.

Comment: @Stack Does that mean I need to build a plugin?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8201281/8150371  , it is using urllib  instead of requests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the reqeusts library, and define a function as a part of a view.

Alternatively you can define a simple tag if you want it to be globally accessible.

For instance

```
import requests
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_site_source(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    return res.text
```

and in the template:

```
...
{% get_site_source url %}
...
```